# What's $K$ (if it exists) in $\prod_{w \leq p < z} \left(1- \frac{1}{\phi(p)}\right)^{-1} \leq K \left(\frac{\log z}{\log w}\right)$?

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to find $K$ (if it exists) such that for all $z$ and $w > 2$, $$\prod_{w \leq p < z} \left(1- \frac{1}{\phi(p)}\right)^{-1} \leq K \left(\frac{\log z}{\log w}\right).$$  Here $p$ is a prime number and $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

The product is $\prod_{w \leq p < z} \left(1+ \frac{1}{p-2} \right)$, and taking logs gives, as $z, w \to \infty$, $$\sum_{w \leq p < z} \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{p-2}\right) = \sum_{w \leq p < z} \frac{1}{p-2} + O\left(\frac{1}{(p-2)^2}\right) $$ $$\leq \sum_{w \leq p < z} \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{w(w-2)} \cdot (z-w) + o(1) \ll \log \log z - \log \log w,$$ by Mertens' Theorem.  (I guess we also have to assume $w$ doesn't grow too slow compared to $z$, so that we can drop the term $\frac{z-w}{w(w-2)}.$)  So exponentiating does give $\prod_{w \leq p < z} \left(1- \frac{1}{\phi(p)}\right)^{-1} \ll \frac{\log z}{\log w}.$  I'm just unsure about the explicit $K$...

Could anyone help me find a $K$?  It doesn't have to be the best possible.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since $\ln( 1+x)<x$, $$\sum \log\left(1+\frac1{p-2}\right)<\sum\frac1p<\log\log z-\log\log w$$

Therefore, $K=1$ which makes your inequality neater. Also, as you don’t need a very good $K$, this value is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for this simplification!  The first inequality may need some extra (very minor) constant to be true (it doesn't follow from $\log(1+x) < x$, though just about!), and the second may as well.  But one exists by Mertens' Theorem, and the wikipedia page says $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p} - \log \log n$$ does not exceed $M + \frac{4}{\log 3} + \frac{2}{3 \log 3} < 6,$ where $M$ is Mertens' constant.  I'll fix the details.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems